# Class declaration cannot close over value 'fulfill' defined in outer scope - Swift 2.0

Tags: xcode, swift, closures, promise

I'm trying to convert my app from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2.0 and I'm encountering the following error:

```
class B {
    func test() -> Promise<A> {
        return Promise<A> { (fulfill, reject) -> Void in
            anotherPromise.then { _ -> Void in
                return fulfill(A()) // Class declaration cannot close over value 'fulfill' defined in outer scope
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make `B` (or the `then` closure) capture `fulfill` properly?

PS: `Promise` comes from [PromiseKit](http://promisekit.org/), and I'm running Xcode 7 beta 1.

Comment: Looks like PromiseKit is not ready for Swift 2.0. Did you get it to compile for the new SDK?

Comment: @JohnDifool PromiseKit has a `swift-2.0` branch which compiles fine on Xcode 7 beta 1: https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/tree/swift-2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to workaround this by assigning `fulfill` to a local that you capture instead.

```
class B {
    func test() -> Promise<A> {
        return Promise<A> { (fulfill, reject) -> Void in
            let innerFulfill = fulfill // close on this instead
            anotherPromise.then { _ -> Void in
                return innerFulfill(A()) // Class declaration cannot close over value 'fulfill' defined in outer scope
            }
        }
    }
}
```